# Drupal 8 Jquery conflict once logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-theming

I'm using Foundation to develop a Drupal theme and, obviously, it requires jQuery.
When I'm logged out from Drupal everything's perfect.

Once I log in, Drupal loads a bunch of libraries among which its own jQuery.
This causes a conflict and breaks the site.

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

How can I solve this?

Comment: I solved the problem using a downloaded version of jQuery instead of the one provided in the core by d8. A temporary solution for sure...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with core jQuery. I used the below code for replacing the version with the one i wanted

**my_theme.theme**

```
function my_theme_js_alter(&$javascript, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  // Swap out jQuery to use an updated version of the library.
  $javascript['core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_theme') . '/script/jquery-2.2.4.js';
  $javascript['core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_theme') . '/script/jquery-2.2.4.min.js';
}
```

Then used the jquery as dependency in libraries

**my_theme.libraries.yml**

```
web-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/jquery.fancybox.min.css: {}
      css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css: {}
  js:
    script/jquery.fancybox.min.js: {}
    script/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Hope it will help